# SOAP deserialization of DateTime object with value "0000-00-00" fails

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime, soap

I have a simple application that gets data records via SOAP. The SOAP webservice was added via "service references" to the project. The calls work fine. I just have a problem when the data holds the value `0000-00-00` for a date which the reference code will store into an `DateTime`-object. The `DateTime` class has foreseen a minimal value of `0001-0-01` which will ultimately lead to the error upon deserializing the response from a SOAP call.

The code that gets executed to pull the data via SOAP is the following:

```
TopixSOAP.TOPIXRPCClient soap = new TopixSOAP.TOPIXRPCClient();
soap.GetProjekt(out error_code, out start_date, out end_date, instance, user, passwd, project_number);
```

So I provide the neccessary information to the SOAP call and it performs well if the start_date and end_date are => `0001-01-01`. But since the data sometimes contains values for the dates of `0000-00-00` the application crashes naturally on deserializing the the value into an `DateTime` object.

I tried to wrap all the out parameters into a separate class called TopixProject:

```
public class TOPIXProject
{

    public TOPIXProject()
    {
    }
    public string ErrorCode
    {
        get
        {
            return ErrorCode;
        }
        set
        {
            ErrorCode = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return StartDate; 
        }
        set
        {
            StartDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }

    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return EndDate;
        }
        set
        {
            EndDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
```

Here the modified call:

```
soap.SOAP_GetProject(out p.ErrorCode, out p.StartDate, out p.EndDate, instance, user, passwd, project_number);
```

The class should set the value to `DateTime.MinValue` so I don't get the error anymore. It dosn't work as I intended to: The members of the class `TOPIXProject` can't be used as out or ref parameters for a function.

If i provide "raw" out variables that I declare before the SOAP call, it works if the dates are in the valid range (=> `0001-01-01`) of the `DateTime` class definitions:

```
string error_code = "";
DateTime start_date, end_date;
soap.GetProjekt(out error_code, out start_date, out end_date, instance, user, passwd, project_number);
```

But I have a lot of data records where the date is `0000-00-00` and it can't be changed (it's an internal marking of unterminatable projects).
So what do I need to do to get valid SOAP responses?

- mainly if the date of the data set is `0000-00-00` I want to get a `DateTime.MinValue`
- Or can I tell the service reference to interpret everything as a string? (Because the service reference builds the code itself and tries to parse the xsd:date type to DateTime, which is in my case pretty bad)

### **Edit:**

I now use part of the SOAP calls from the service reference (basically all where no dates are passed back). For the rest I implemented a SOAPHelper class which provides the necccessary calls to the SOAP endpoint and returns mostly strings or XML. Code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2435843/526709)

Comment: do you have control over the service implementation? will the service contract change?

Comment: You mean changing the server side code that generates the WSDL? sadly not. It's a pretty black box like system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We came up with a different solution: Since the Webservice is not minding the xsi:type attributes in the XML we figured it would be the easest way to proxy the traffic and manipulate the WSDL file and the in and out going XML messages.

Therefore we wrote a PHP script that is controled via the $_GET variables:

- returns the WSDL file (manipulated)
- filters the xml contents and replaces certain strings so we get all xsi:date nodes as xsi:string nodes

It's not the cleanest way possible but the only way to circumvent problem.

```
<?php
/** A simple HTTP/SOAP proxy server with response manipulation
*
*  @author: Dipl.-Ing. (FH) Tom Gottschalk, tom.gottschalk@gmail.com
*
*  Usage:
*  1.  proxy.php?wsdl:
*      - gets the original WSDL file content from the SOAP server
*      - manipulates the types `date` and `time` to `string`
*      - manipulates the SOAP service URI binding to `proxy.php?proxy`
*  2.  proxy.php?proxy
*      - forwards the original HTTP request to the SOAP server
*      - fetches the HTTP response
*      - manipulates the types `date` and `time` to `string` in the HTTP response
*      - returns the manipulated SOAP (HTTP) response
*/

// suppress deprecated and strict standard messages
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);

// what to do: serve WSDL or work as Proxy server
if(array_key_exists("proxy", $_GET)) {
proxy();
}
elseif(array_key_exists("wsdl", $_GET))
{
wsdl();
}

// manipulate data types in the XML WSDL or SOAP response
function manipulate($xml)
{
$xml = str_replace('type="xsd:date"', 'type="xsd:string"', $xml);
$xml = str_replace('type="xsd:time"', 'type="xsd:string"', $xml);
return $xml;
}

function proxy()
{
// fetch all HTTP request headers from the current request
$headers = apache_request_headers();
// get all raw POST data
$rawPostData = file_get_contents("php://input"); # alternatively:       $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

// URI to request
$uri = "http://<server:port>/INCOMING_PORT/";

// do request and get response
$request = new HttpRequest($uri, HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$request->addHeaders($headers);
$request->setRawPostData($rawPostData);
$response = $request->send();

// send headers
foreach($response->getHeaders() as $key => $value) {
    header(sprintf("%s: %s", $key, $value));
}

// edit response body
$body = $response->getBody();
$body = manipulate($body);

// return response
echo $body;
}

function wsdl()
{
// get original WSDL file
$uri = "http://<server:port>/WSDL/";
$wsdl = file_get_contents($uri);
// manipulate data types
$wsdl = manipulate($wsdl);
// manipulate SOAP service URI binding
$wsdl = str_replace('http://<server:port>/INCOMING_PORT/', 'http://url_to_php_proxy_script/proxy.php?proxy', $wsdl);
// return result
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $wsdl;
}
?>
```

TL,DR: We used a proxified WSDL since the xsi:type isn't minded by the server.

Answer (score 1):

your best choice would be to generate the client side by hand (or using  [Svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) tool)
and modify the contract to receive a message, instead of datetime. that way you could interact with the message itself and handle the invalid date-time values. there is a nice post about using the feature [here](http://lookingsharp.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/custom-message-handling-with-wcf-part-1-of-2/) more about [Using Message Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) on msdn.

Comment: I now call the SOAP requests manually using HttpWebRequest. It's not pretty but it works. The burdens of a unskilled programmer working with poorly declared data. Thanks for all your effort Iga!